# which is the fastest tanh approximation to be implemented in FPGA

Tags: neural-network, fpga, hyperbolic-function

I want to implement a neural net on FPGA, and I need a fast function to calculate (approxmite) tanh.

Accuracy of 2 digit after point will be enough.

Comment: Look up the **cordic** algorithm. It may not be the fastest but it is a good start.

Comment: Hi, I know about CORDIC algorithm. But I need fast. Because I need tanh to implement a function in FPGA, it must be calculated quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.planetmath.org/taylorseriesofhyperbolicfunctions
This looks fast enough, depending on your needs. You can add more, or discard the higher terms, and keep the first few for speed, e.g.: (python syntax)

```
x-1/3*x**3+2/15*x**5
```

If you also need the derivative, it's easy to calculate for polinomials. (AFAIR you need that for back propagation)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It really works, but I need even faster.  x**3 and x**5 are much costly. Maybe within 2-3 clock cycle.

Comment: Is this for the training or the execution part? Is tanh fixed, or you can replace it with relu (at least in the first few layers)? You might be able to train your ANN separately at first, then upload your already trained net onto the FPGA. I'm not sure you're optimizing the relevant part of your implementation.

Comment: Yes, It is only for execution part.  Also, I am using tanh on only one layer.  It is performing well on tanh or sigmoid. But poor performance on relu.

Comment: I think the formula you have provided is fast enough for me.  I will let you know after consulting with my instructor.